# How to retrieve Bluetooth Address through Name from Paired/bonded device list?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I actually do this when I'm discovering devices:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            this.registerReceiver(mDiscovery, filter);
```

And in my in my Broadcastreceiver:

```
String action = intent.getAction();

if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
```

And then I can do **device.getName()** and **device.getAddress()**.

My problem is, I only know how to do this with an **intent** for the discovery. So, android devices as fair as I know have list with paired devices with their names as respective addresses.

Given the name, how can I directly (without discovery and so without a broadcast receiver) get the address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you created an object of your BluetoothAdapter ( let's say mBluetoothAdatper) you can get a list with all of the bonded(paired) devices with mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(). 
More information on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29).

Comment: With this you can use device.getName() and device.getAddress() in the remote devices.